# I find to SourceToken option in CustomerCreateOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

In following code SourceToken option is used, but I cannot find SourceToken option in references of CreateCustomerOptions in Visual Studio or pressing f12 key. Instead I see there an option of Source, are both options same not not ?
Need help with this issue..

Here I'm giving link of code:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of Stripe's .NET SDK (v27), this has changed, and instead of `SourceToken` you'll need to pass the token/source id as `Source`

```
    var createOptions = new CustomerCreateOptions
    {
        Email = "example@example.com",
        Source = "tok_123",
    };
```

See [library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/Customers/CustomerCreateOptions.cs#L94) [source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/StripeTests/Services/Customers/CustomerServiceTest.cs#L27-L31) code.

Comment: but I have an issue that, customer is not created, loading continues in browser after submit button click but nothing happens. Customer is not created.

Comment: when debugged, on following line it goes to browser on keeps on running don't create customer. and shows no error too. `Customer customer = service.Create(options);`